# Why is this API request working on my local, but no on production?

Tags: php, dreamhost, eventbrite

```
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=[MY_API_KEY]'); echo $result;
```

This logs stuff fine on my local environment, but not on production, where it returns completely blank. I also tried ssh'ing into my production server and running

```
curl https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=[MY_API_KEY]
```

and that worked fine as well. What's going on? Could my hosting provider (Dreamhost) be blocking me somehow?

Comment: is [`allow_url_fopen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) off?

Comment: Never heard of that, did some research, and found that 1) I have no idea how to see if it's on or off on my hosting provider (Dreamhost) and 2) that the PHP cURL library/methods should circumvent that stuff. I enabled the cURL stuff in my php.ini locally, but still no dice. I'm using the Eventbrite PHP API, and initializing an Eventbrite object like this: `require 'api/eventbrite/Eventbrite.php';
$eb_client = new Eventbrite( array('app_key'=>'MYAPPKEY',
         'user_key'=>'MYUSERKEY'));`

Comment: Closed, it was a careless mistake.